# L2 error of a convection-diffusion equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, estimation

I am given a pde of the following type:

\begin{align}
-\Delta f + \vec{a}\cdot \nabla f + f &= g\quad \text{in }\Omega:=B_1(0)\subset\mathbb{R}^2\\
f &= 0\quad \text{on }\partial\Omega
\end{align}

with $\vec{a} = (1,1)^t$. For which I have to derive an estimation of the form 
$||\nabla^2 f||_{L^2} = |\Delta f|_{H^2} \leq c||g||_{L^2}$ (I think it should be the seminorm on $H^2$).

Multiplying by $-\Delta f$ and integrating over the domain yields the following estimate:

\begin{align}
||\Delta f||^2_{L^2} &= - \int g \Delta f dx+ \int f\Delta f dx+ \int \Delta f(\vec{a}\cdot \nabla f)dx\\
&= -(g,\Delta f)_{L^2} +(\vec{a}\cdot\nabla f,\Delta f)_{L^2} - ||\nabla f||_{L^2}^2\\
&\leq |(g,\Delta f)| + |(\vec{a}\cdot\nabla f,\Delta f) - ||\nabla f|||\\
&\leq ||g|| ||\Delta f|| + \frac{1}{2}||\Delta f||^2
\end{align}

here I ommit the $L^2$ subscript in line 3 for brevity. To obtain the last inequality I use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality on the first term and for the second term the Cauchy inequality:

\begin{equation}
(\vec{a}\cdot\nabla f,\Delta f) \leq |(\vec{a}\cdot\nabla f,\Delta f)|\leq ||\vec{a}\cdot\nabla f|| ||\Delta f||\leq \frac{1}{2}||\Delta f||^2 + ||\nabla f||^2
\end{equation}

subtracting $||\nabla f||^2$ on both sides yields the desired estimate.

*My first question* is: Is this estimation correct?

Now I am given a hint to use the auxiliary problem
\begin{align}
-\Delta u &= h :=-\Delta f\quad \text{in }\Omega\\
u &= 0 \quad\text{on }\partial\Omega
\end{align}
to arrive at the desired estimate (which will then be used with the Aubin-Nitsche trick on the auxiliary problem to obtain an estimate of the $L^2$ approximation error).

At this point I am stuck and would like to ask for a hint how to get to the final estimate $||\nabla^2 f||_{L^2} = |\Delta f|_{H^2} \leq c||g||_{L^2}$.

A further guess of mine is:

I know by application of Lax-Milgram, that the original PDE has a solution $f\in H_0^1(\Omega)$. I think I could use a remark from the lecture which says that the Poisson problem (the auxiliary in this case) has a solution in $H^{k+1}$ if $\partial\Omega\in C^k$ and $ h \in H^{k-1}$.
A soultion $f\in H^1_0$ does not imply $-\Delta f\in H^{k\geq 0}$ but if I reformulate the Poisson problem in a weak formulation I get $(-\nabla u,\nabla \phi) =(-\Delta f, \phi) \equiv (\nabla f,\nabla\phi)$ and $\nabla f\in H^0=L^2$
thus the remark *would* be applicable.

Comment: Shouldn't the inequality be $\| \Delta f \|_{L^2} = \| \nabla^2 f \|_{L^2} = | f |_{H^2} \leq C \| g \|_{L^2}$? The $H^2$ seminorm is usually the $L^2$ norm of the Laplacian. Your argument looks fine to me, but the order doesn't work out: You cannot apply your last argument (Cauchy-Schwarz + Young) if you already took the absolute value and applied the triangle inequality. But you can apply it before you take the absolute value.

Comment: To be more clear about my last remark: For me the canceling of $\| \nabla f \|$ in your argument looked kind of shady because your inequality reads $|(\vec{a}\cdot\nabla f,\Delta f) - ||\nabla f|||$ but you just estimated $(\vec{a}\cdot\nabla f,\Delta f)$ and then canceled $\| \nabla f \|$. If you just do the same estimate for $(\vec{a}\cdot\nabla f,\Delta f)$ earlier it's fine.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In fact, when deriving the estimate, I did use the estimate for $(\vec{a}\cdot\nabla f, \Delta f)$ before I introduced the absolute value on both sides of the equality. As for the final estimate, it has been corrected.

Comment: I see I messed up my notation in a few places, including the auxiliary problem. I changed it to make it explicit, that it is independent of $g$. Which is my problem, because even if I have a solution $u\in H^1_0$ for it I don't see how to get from it to $||\Delta f||_{L^2}$